# Under what conditions does simple iterative method converge

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ positive semi-definite symmetric matrix with a non-trivial null space.  Consider the problem
\begin{equation} Ax = b  \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (1) \end{equation}

> State the condition that guarantees a solution to (1) will exist, and derive the condition on matrix $A$ that insures the iterative method,
>   $$ x_{k+1} = x_k + \big( b - Ax_k \big), \;\; k = 0,1,2,\dots $$
>   will converge to a solution of (1), when a solution to (1) exists.

Never been faced with a problem like this, I am not sure where to start.  I have tried to start several different ways, but they all seem to be nonsense. Any suggestions/solutions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is symmetric, we can presume that it is diagonal for the purposes of 
the analysis.

Write $A= \begin{bmatrix} \Lambda & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, with $\Lambda$ invertible
 and $b= \begin{bmatrix} \beta \\ \gamma \end{bmatrix}$ in the appropriate basis.

Then $Ax=b$ has a solution **iff** $b \in {\cal R} A$ **iff** $\gamma = 0$.

Then if we write $x_k = \begin{bmatrix} y_k \\ z_k \end{bmatrix}$, the iteration becomes
$y_{k+1} = (I-\Lambda) y_k + \beta$, $z_{k+1} = z_k$.

From this we can see that one sufficient condition for convergence from any initial point would be that the non zero eigenvalues of $A$ lie in $(0,2)$,
or, in other words, all eigenvalues of $A$ must be less than $2$.

Comment: Would another way to state the last sentence be that the spectral radius of $(I - \Lambda)$ is less than 1?  And I guess if $A = P\Lambda P^{-1}$, then we can look at this problem in the diagonal basis because it only introduces a constant (the condition number of $P$) into the problem, which doesn't affect convergence.

Comment: Not quite, because $A$ is singular, so it has at least one eigenvalue at $0$.

Comment: Numerics are another issue, it is possible that fp. errors would 'leak' into the null space and the component in the null space would not remain constant.

Comment: But the spectral radius of $(I - \Lambda)$ must be strictly less than 1?

Comment: I'm sorry, I saw $A$, not $\Lambda$ above. Yes, you are correct. Since $A$ is symmetric we can express the condition as an interval of the reals.

Comment: Not a problem, thanks for the help this all makes a lot of sense! Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if that is what your teacher is looking for but that is how I wolc approach it.

Comment: No teacher, just studying.  I think this approach makes a lot of sense now that I see it, thanks